# CoreData(iOS):Do I need to create a database to use CoreData ?Can coredata operate on a simple flat file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am pretty new to CoreData Programming but would like to ask:

> *Do I need to create a database to use CoreData ? Can coredata operate on a simple flat file ?*

Please provide suitable references & links.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data provides four native types of persistent store:

- SQLite
- Binary
- XML
- In-Memory

These store types each offer different benefits and tradeoffs, and are described in “Persistent Store Features”. **The Binary and XML stores are "atomic” stores—they must be read and written in their entirety, *unlike the SQLite store* which can be modified piecemeal, one record at a time if you wish.**

Refer to the first link ([pdf](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=create%20a%20custom%20atomic%20store%20type%20in%20iOS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a))

Comment: You asked for something else, and you are posting this as an answer!!! Or We failed to understand your question?

Comment: Dear @AnoopVaidya, i wanted to know that is a DB (sqlite or anything) necessary to use coredata. The pdf says that we can create our own atomic stores for data storage.So i think i can save my entire data to an xml and retreive it using coredata but unfortunately xml must be read and written in entirety :(.
Hope you understood the Q n A.

Comment: But I am not sure, are you not willing to use core data in your application? However you can use some other database with a running server.